Looking for an older (but color) movie that ends with an evil scientist's laboratory being destroyed, perhaps by fire
This movie involves a young woman who is lured into transformation experiments (perhaps involving insects) being performed by an evil scientist.  The movie setting was likely the 1970's. I seem to remember it was filmed outside the US, and may have been independent, as the actors had accents and the cars didn't look american, but i think it was in english.  It also involved a husband and wife on holiday...   likely made in the 70's or early 80's?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Who survives?  Do the husband and wife?  Does the young woman?  Is she spared being transformed, reverted, or left transformed?

Hi, thanks for your quick response. I don't remember for sure, but im guessing the couple survives.  I think they were on holiday, a motor trip, and were unrelated to the young woman, who may have been a local.  and i dont remember the young woman actually being transformed...

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Also, it was in a semi-rural setting. Hilly, with woods.  May have even been a lumbermill somewhere in the movie.  The opening scenes had the young woman walking in a sundress in the woods....

I finally found it...  Venom, 1971.

On holiday in Bavaria, Paul Greville meets a girl in a forest. He later finds out she is Anna, and she has a spider-shaped mark on her shoulder. The locals believe she is the "spider goddess" responsible for several violent deaths. It later emerges that Anna's father, Dr. Lutgermann, is a Nazi war criminal who has developed a deadly nerve drug based on spiders' venom. He created the legend of the spider goddess as a cover for his killing of intruders. Paul and Anna escape while Lutgermann, attacked by deadly spiders released by Anna, accidentally sets fire to his house. Anna rushes back to try to save him.


You could improve your answer (and likely earn more reputation) if you added a synopsis or more details about this.
